# Finding a niche tag that the reputation leaders aren't active in

Tags: discussion, data-dump

Bill said:

> Pick a niche tag that the reputation
>   leaders aren't active in and start
>   studying up on that. This is a great
>   way to pick up some stray reputation
>   points and learn something new at the
>   same time.

[Should I work really hard to get back on the first page of users on StackOverflow, or try to get a life?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11345/work-hard-or-get-a-life/11379#11379)

Any candidate SQL queries against the data dump?

Comment: belongs on SO ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the dude obliges:

```
Tag                            Questions   Ratio                                   AvgReputation
------------------------------ ----------- --------------------------------------- -------------
cakephp                        382         3.5314136125654                         409
subsonic                       385         2.6857142857142                         564
flex3                          302         2.1158940397350                         614
j2me                           317         3.5457413249211                         659
uitableview                    254         2.2795275590551                         686
vb                             392         4.4336734693877                         688
homework                       1087        9.8206071757129                         711
facebook                       254         3.7322834645669                         735
sharepoint2007                 272         2.6433823529411                         754
object                         224         7.2455357142857                         767
dropdownlist                   202         3.6534653465346                         787
div                            300         5.7500000000000                         804
jsf                            329         2.7446808510638                         808
wordpress                      332         3.8253012048192                         808
csv                            299         6.4615384615384                         829
actionscript-3                 1466        3.0607094133697                         830
blackberry                     216         3.9814814814814                         849
form                           323         4.3498452012383                         860
xsl                            208         4.5384615384615                         866
textbox                        256         3.6914062500000                         870
drupal                         282         4.1950354609929                         870
javascript-events              218         4.1330275229357                         888
mobile                         304         4.8190789473684                         917
login                          248         5.3225806451612                         919
nhibernate-mapping             204         1.9411764705882                         926
objective-c                    3029        6.5335094090458                         927
upload                         262         4.4427480916030                         930
iis7                           393         2.6768447837150                         930
plsql                          263         5.6045627376425                         931
select                         336         4.8511904761904                         931
ssis                           370         2.2567567567567                         943
query                          901         5.3196448390677                         944
ms-access                      1072        4.4011194029850                         947
ssrs                           377         2.5305039787798                         950
ubuntu                         269         6.4572490706319                         950
flash                          1870        3.4914438502673                         955
fluent-nhibernate              244         2.0819672131147                         960
ruby-on-rails                  3954        5.7278705108750                         960
iphone                         5453        4.6128736475334                         966
entity-framework               784         3.4387755102040                         969
coldfusion                     333         8.0480480480480                         972
redirect                       298         4.2986577181208                         972
google-maps                    316         3.8386075949367                         983
air                            272         2.6470588235294                         986
activerecord                   442         4.8076923076923                         987
iphone-sdk                     1961        3.6955634880163                         987
jsp                            698         3.5716332378223                         992
file                           633         7.1990521327014                         998
jboss                          285         2.3508771929824                         999
django-models                  321         4.8878504672897                         1005
```

What these numbers mean:

The higher the magic ratio number is, the more lucrative the tag is reputation wise. The AvgReputation is the average reputation of all the contributors. Community wiki is excluded.

The SQL:

```
create view TotalQuestionValue as
select 
    q.Id, 
    Total = sum(p.Score) + q.Score, 
    TotalExcludingWiki = sum(case when p.CommunityOwnedDate is not null then 0 else p.Score end) + 
        case when q.CommunityOwnedDate is not null then 0 else q.Score end
from Questions q
join Posts p on p.ParentId = q.Id 
group by q.Id, q.Score, q.CommunityOwnedDate

select 
    t.TagName, 
    Questions = count(t.TagName), 
    [Value] = sum(TotalExcludingWiki), 
    [Ratio] = sum(TotalExcludingWiki) / (count(t.TagName) + 0.0) 
into #QuestionValue
from PostTags p
join Tags t on t.Id = p.TagId
join TotalQuestionValue q on q.Id = p.PostId
group by t.TagName
having count(t.TagName) > 50


select 
    t.TagName, 
    AvgReputation = avg(Reputation)
into #AvgRep
from PostTags p
join Tags t on t.Id = p.TagId
join Posts a on a.Id = p.PostId
join Users u on u.Id = a.OwnerUserId
group by t.TagName
having count(*) > 50


select top 1000 * 
from #QuestionValue q
join #AvgRep a on q.TagName = a.TagName
where Questions > 200
order by a.AvgReputation asc
```

Comment: Huh. My SSIS answers have usually only netted me 1-2 upvotes, where as my simplistic SQL answers are usually 3-4.

Comment: Ah! I don't have enough arbitrary points to +1 you on Meta! But kudos for the Lebowski reference...

Comment: yeah ssis is not that lucrative, but there are not many high rep users lurking on that tag

Answer (score 2):

Now we know where to target next! mwahaha. Mwa ha ha.

## MWA HA HA HAAAAAAAAaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.......

(cough, splutter, wheeze... less "aaa" next time...)

I'm kidding... <kbd>homework</kbd> is all yours...

Answer (score 1):

So...

```
Tag        Questions   Ratio              AvgReputation
---------- ----------- ------------------ ---------------
homework   1087        9.8206071757129    711
```

Who's going to be the `homework` rep leader?

Comment: lots of newbies participate in this tag and its very lucrative ...

Comment: If you don't have the long time users coming in and trying to shut them down.

Comment: Who do you *think* is the rep leader? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=homework&sort=stats&pagesize=15

Comment: Whoa. When did I start getting on top-20 lists? :)